# How do I reset directory settings?

Tags: configuration, images, directory

Discovering a problem with image uploads (no directory available in CK) I thought I should set the Resource Directory for images as per recommended using a variable, so I set it to "[cms.root]/images".

Now our site is not loading, giving a `Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path"`.

1. I think Civi really needs to verify that the directory exists before saving the setting
2. How do I reset that directory to something that makes the site live again?

I only changed the path to the image directory.

By overriding the image URL in `civicrm.settings.php` I managed to get the admin interface up again. But the site is still erroring out with `Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path"`. And the values in the Resource URL dialogue are read-only since they are overridden.

Are the original setting stored in the database? How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database for your installation there is a table named `civicrm_setting`. Using SequelPRO, myPhpAdmin or something similar you will find entries for all settings, including the directory settings, here.

I was looking for the image upload directory and found

```
39    imageUploadDir    s:17:"[cms.root]/images";
```

With `mysql` you can do

```
select value from civicrm_setting where name = 'imageUploadDir';
```

The initial part (`s:17`) means that the content is a 's'tring with length 17, so I changed the content of the string to something reasonable, taking that into account, and the site worked again.

Don't forget to remove any possible overrides you made in `civicrm.settings.php`.

Also if your CiviCRM menus disappear you probably changed it to something different that it originally was.